# not able to select file array value in from input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find if the user uploaded any image..

Following is the code

```
<input type="file"  name="profile_gallery[]">
<div id='submiform'>submit</div>
```

I tried two methods first one

```
    $(function(){
      $('#submitform').on('click', function(){
         alert($('input[name=profile_gallery]').val());
      });
    });
```

and the error is

```
    alert($('input[name=profile_gallery]').val());  //show undefined after and before selecting the file
```

second one

```
    $(function(){
      $('#submitform').on('click', function(){
            var profile_gallery = ($('input[name=profile_gallery]'))[0].files;  
            alert(profile_gallery.length);
      });
    });
```

and the error is

```
    alert(profile_gallery.length);  //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
```

Comment: `input[name^=profile_gallery]` is one possible selector to get it. But why do you need such a name?

Comment: @raina77ow brilliant bro thanks it worked, but could you please explain why it worked..

Comment: @vSugumar Here you go: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: `$('input[name=profile_gallery]')` doesn't work because `"profile_gallery"` is **not** equal to `"profile_gallery[]"`. `$('input[name^=profile_gallery]')` works because both `"profile_gallery"` and `"profile_gallery[]"` begins with `profile_gallery`.

Answer (score 2):

> This can be achieve using [FileAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File),

with several options

- **File.name** : Returns the name of the file referenced by the File object.
- **File.size** :Returns the size of the file.
- **File.type** : Returns the MIME type of the file.

and fore more [go here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)